# BadImage error when installing software on Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB 64bit. Every time I try to install a software I get an BadImage error

[image]

I have tried to install different software (Firefox 32bit/64bit, Opera 32bit/64bit, 7Zip 32bit/64bit, Chrome) and always get the same error. I have tried all this as normal user or Run As Administrator with same result.

I have also try running *sfc /scannow*, but the scan never finishes and crashes after 83% with message: “Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation”. I have also tried this in SafeMode.

Other thinks I've tried:

- ChkDsk – error still there
- Windows Reset – will not let me proceed
- Windows Update – always fails
- *Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup* finished with error "Component store has been corrupted"
- I have downloaded image from our MSDN and tried to repair the image using `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess` but this has failed as well

The device came with OS pre-installed already and I do not have ISO image or the option to re-install the windows.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: You can always use the [Microsoft Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10) to create Windows installation media.

Comment: @DanielB if I try to install the software, I get same error. If I just unzip it, there are SetupHost.exe and DiagTrackRunner.exe, but they don't seem to run anything...

Comment: Then I suggest using a different PC to create a setup medium.

Comment: @DanielB see my update re: image repair